# Go linked list pointer assignment from non-pointer struct element

Tags: pointers, go, linked-list

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/container/list/list.go#L49

I am having hard time why I am getting `cannot assign to pointer` error in Go.

Here's the code that works: http://play.golang.org/p/P9FjK8A-32 which is same as Go's original container/list code

```
type List struct {
    root Element
    len  int
}

type Element struct {
    next, prev *Element
    list       *List
    Value      interface{}
}
```

The original code has `root` as a value and reference it everytime it needs to be in pointer type but why not at first place define `root` as a pointer?

```
type List struct {
    root *Element
    len  int
}

type Element struct {
    next, prev *Element
    list       *List
    Value      interface{}
}
```

This give me an error: http://play.golang.org/p/1gCAR_rcx1 -> `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

Why am I getting this error?
Why does Go define `root` as a non-pointer value when it defines `next`, and `prev` as pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is `nil` by default and needs to be initialized.

This:

```
// Init initializes or clears list l.
func (l *List) Init() *List {
  l.root.next = l.root
  l.root.prev = l.root
  l.len = 0
  return l
}
```

should become this:

```
// Init initializes or clears list l.
func (l *List) Init() *List {
  l.root = new(Element) // necessary to avoid dereferencing a nil pointer
  l.root.next = l.root
  l.root.prev = l.root
  l.len = 0
  return l
}
```

Demo at http://play.golang.org/p/EYSscTMYnn

In the case of the standard library, it is not necessary to have `root` be a pointer, however, for `prev` and `next` it is necessary, otherwise the struct definition would be recursive, which is not allowed, because it would in theory cause a struct of infinite size...